# Calculating Fourier Transform of $e^{-a|x|}$

Tags: fourier-transform

How can I calculate the Fourier transform of
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{ax},  & -\infty \lt x \le 0 \\
e^{-ax}, &  0 \lt x \lt \infty \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $a\gt 0$ is a constant?

I know that the Fourier transform is defined as $$ \mathcal{F} f (\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-i\omega x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$ but i just don't know how to tackle this.

Comment: Separate into an integral from $-\infty$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $\infty$.